# Besides returning the data, is there a way to pass up variables to a different scope in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, scope

Here's a pretty obscure one; and I know that I'm reaching here - but I'm trying to find an 'elegant' solution to adding a number of variables to [effectively] the parent scope.

Here's the example:

```
File 1:
<?
ImportPost();

// Do something with imported variables.
?>

File 2: 
<?   
function ImportPOST()
{
    foreach( $_POST as $Key => $Value )
        VariableToParentScope($Key, $Value);
}
?>
```

So that I would end up with the 'simple' variable names in my first ('DoSomething') method. One thing I find myself doing over and over again is building this small foreach to perform this exact task - but I don't see many other ways to achieve it, other than placing it all in a class - which is generally preferable anyway, but let's say this is in the context of a file that is just some non-OOP PHP.

I've also considered reading the contents of 'File 1', inserting the variables before the rest of the files contents, and then running it - and while this may be the closest thing to a 'proper' implementation there is, I'm still trying to figure out if there is a simpler, or more appropriate one.

Any thoughts?

I.E. - Edit the stack? 0_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [extract](http://php.net/extract) to build some variables from an array - here's an example:

```
function importVars()
{
    return array('foo'=>'xyzzy', 'bar'=>'123');
}


function demo()
{
    extract(importVars());

    echo "foo is $foo\n";
    echo "bar is $bar\n";
}

demo();
```

I'd be wary of doing this with external data such as from $_POST - better to carefully validate what you're bringing in.

Comment: Bingo... I'll have to do some testing, but for now I'm going to give you the &lt;3 and the answer. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php), which essentially would make your variables available in the global scope:

```
//assuming $_POST = ['foo'=>'bar']

echo $foo; // Notice: Undefined variable

function ImportPOST()
{
    foreach( $_POST as $Key => $Value )
        $GLOBALS[$key] = $Value;
}

ImportPOST();
echo $foo; // "bar".
```

However, as you said yourself, it's bad practice to interfere the global scope in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a potential security risk to me.  I would push all the vars to an array, then pass that around.  Or at most, add this array to the global scope.   That way, you keep all post data contained in one place, rather than at the same level as all other global variables.